I can't open Jupyter with command showing the given error
C:\Users\USER>jupyter notebook
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:35.491 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:35.507 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:35.523 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:35.523 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.194 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.257 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.272 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.272 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.272 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.272 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.272 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.741 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.757 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.757 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\USER
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.757 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.14.2 is running at:
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.757 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/tree?token=f5f2c842d17b41d1f2197a82176e6508d6f9df3723ab5904
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.757 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=f5f2c842d17b41d1f2197a82176e6508d6f9df3723ab5904
[I 2024-09-09 11:00:36.757 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[E 2024-09-09 11:00:36.757 ServerApp] Failed to write server-info to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\jpserver-11656.json: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 623, in launch_instance
    serverapp.start()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 3120, in start
    self.start_app()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 3024, in start_app
    self.write_browser_open_files()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2891, in write_browser_open_files
    self.write_browser_open_file()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2914, in write_browser_open_file
    with open(self.browser_open_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\jpserver-11656-open.html

I don't know what to do.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
